# I am trying to call a Controller Action using View::share

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to pass a variable to every view when a user is logged in, and I put the action in my `routes.php` file;

```
//functions only execute when the user is logged in
 Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){

       View::share('ctxr', 'user is authenticated');

 });
```

I am currently using `Laravel 4.2` and using a static variable the share function works as expected. If I call the `{{ $ctxr }}` from any partial or view, it displays correctly, but the problem is, when I have an action on the `basecontroller` and I'm thinking of doing something similar to this:

```
View::share('ctxr', BaseController@getStatistics);
```

Which returns the stats generated to every view. but I keep getting an error, please what is the best way to call controller functions from a `View::share` function. I am trying to avoid using sessions, since `Laravel` has made this available...

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: immediately i posted this, i tried converting the method to a static function,  and calling it ::  ' View::share('ctxr', BaseController::getStats()); ' and it worked... with static methods.... after so many trials...

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter needs to be a string or an array. A callback function won't work, from what I can tell. But what you can do is assign the returned value to a variable and pass that along:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){

    $bc = new BaseController();
    $stats = $bc->getStatistics();
    // Or if getStatistics is defined as a static function
    $stats = BaseController::getStatistics();
    View::share('ctxr', $stats);

});
```

Comment: ...thanks, i love your approach i'd do this, appreciated.